# Any ruby gems to do (Chinese) Transliterate (Romanization), especially for URL?

Tags: ruby, transliteration

> Generally spoken, it takes Unicode text and tries to represent it in
>   US-ASCII characters (universally displayable, unaccented characters)
>   by attempting to transliterate the pronunciation expressed by the text
>   in some other writing system to Roman letters.

ex,

```
"一二三".ooxx => "e-er-san"
```

After doing http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=pinyin I got some rubygems, but none of them are robustly workable for this issue.

Comment: I found that https://github.com/flyerhzm/chinese_pinyin can solve my issue.

Comment: Pinyin.t(title, ' ').scan(/[0-9a-zA-Z]+/).join('-')

Answer (score 0):

Doing this perfectly is almost impossible, since some Chinese characters have two or more pronunciations, for example 银行 = yin hang, 不行 = bu xing (the last character is identical, pronounced hang in one context and xing in the other)... Other than that, you could probably roll your own using the unicode database, which I think has pronunciation info as well. If you want to be more fancy, I think there are some open source input methods which have the mappings, and they'll have them for words too, so that if you find 银行 together, it will know that the second character is hang, not xing. [OpenVanilla](http://code.google.com/p/openvanilla/) might have databases you can work with (OSS).